# Tell VS2010 to collapse regions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, regions

So I have written a t4 template which generates a ton of code and works well.  The only issue is that most of the code never needs to be seen by developers so I have hidden in regions all of the boiler plate code .  Is there any way (i'm assuming no) to give VS a hint in a c++ code file to go ahead and collapse the regions.

Comment: @Tomalak Why its a specific question about how to accomplish something not a theoretical discussion.

Comment: programmers.SE isn't just for theoretical discussion, and SO isn't for specific questions of _any_ topic. This is a question really about a tool that you use in your programming life, not a specific question about a programming language.

Comment: We are going to have to disagree on that one I don't know how question on SO are really only about a language many many are about tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate the code into a separate file and then `#include` it where necessary. That way you won't have developers working directly on top of the generated code: they don't see it, and it makes possible future regenerations of that code very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Use [#pragma region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6xkz944%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). It won't do have regions hidden by default but it will allow you to collapse multiple functions at once.

Comment: But i dont know if it auto collapses